# how to check if user is running Vista or XP

Tags: vb.net

Hi 
How can I check if user running my application is running Vista or XP?
I need to make it
If XP then
msgbox "XP"
else
if Vista then
msgbox "Vista"
endif

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Microsoft KB article on how to do this in C#. The code shouldn't be too hard to translate into VB.NET:

[How to determine the Windows version by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283)

Here's a quick attempt at conversion:

```
Dim osInfo As System.OperatingSystem = System.Environment.OSVersion

Select Case osInfo.Version.Major
    Case 5
        ' Windows 2000 or XP
    Case 6
        ' Windows Vista
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Environment.OSVersion, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

This is Justin Niessner's answer in Visual Basic:

```
Select Case System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
    Case 5
        ' Windows 2000 or XP
    Case 6
        ' Windows Vista or 7 ie. 6.0 and 6.1
End Select
```

[You can find the OS versions here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) If you want a bit more refinement, you can add another case select where you replace System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major with System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor to distinguish say Vista from 7. Eg:

```
Select Case System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
    Case 5
        ' Windows 2000 or XP
    Case 6
        ' Windows Vista or 7 ie. 6.0 and 6.1
        Select Case System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
            Case 0
                'Vista
            Case 1
                '7
            End Select
End Select
```